# Proving convergence of a weighted sum given conditions

Tags: real-analysis

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let the finite sequence $\{b_{n,m}\}_{m=1}^n\subset(0,\infty)$. Assume, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, that  $b_{n,1}+b_{n,2} + \cdots + b_{n,n} = 1$. Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}( b_{n,1}\cdot a_1+b_{n,2}\cdot a_2+\cdots+b_{n,n}\cdot a_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ for every convergent sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset\mathbb{R}$ if and only if, for each $m \in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_{n,m}=0$.

I am not sure how to approach this problem. First of all, I am not even sure how the hypothesis is consistent with what I am trying to prove. Here is what I mean: If we try to prove the <--- direction, we can suppose that $\lim b_{n,1} = 0$, $\lim b_{n,2} = 0$, and so on. Then $\lim(b_{n,1} + b_{n,2}+ \cdots b_{n,n}) = 0$. However, it was given that $b_{n,1}+b_{n,2} + \cdots + b_{n,n} = 1$. So $\lim(1)=1=0$. Where am I going wrong here, and how should I approach this problem in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nuber of terms in $b_{n,1}+b_{n,2}+...+b_{n,n}$ is increasing to $\infty$. Just because each term tends to $0$ you cannot conclude that the sum tends to $0$. For example, If you add $\frac 1 n$ $\,$  $n$ times you get $1$. Each term has limit $0$ but the sum is $1$. Now for a proof: if $b_{n,1}a_1+b_{n,2}a_2+...+b_{n,n}a_n \to c$ whenever $a_n \to c$ take $a_n$ to be $1$ for $n=j$ and $0$ for all other $n$ (where $j$ is fixed). Then you see that $\lim b_{n,j} \to 0$ for each $j$. For the converse part, we have  $b_{n,1}a_1+b_{n,2}a_2+...+b_{n,n}a_n - c=b_{n,1}(a_1-c)+b_{n,2}(a_2-c)+...+b_{n,n}(a_n-c) $. Given $\epsilon >0$ choose $k$ such that $|a_n-c| <\epsilon$ for all $n \geq k$. Then $|b_{n,k}(a_{k}-c)+b_{n,k+1}(a_{k+1}-c)+...+b_{n,n}(a_n-c)|<\epsilon (b_{n,k+1}+b_{n,k+2}+...+b_{n,n})\leq \epsilon$ for $n \geq k$.  Now $|b_{n,1}(a_1-c)+b_{n,2}(a_2-c)+...+b_{n,k-1}(a_{k-1}-c)| \to 0$ becasue there are only a fixed number of terms here and each term has limit $0$.  This finishes the proof.

Comment: For the converse part, how does the equality $b_{n,1}a_1+b_{n,2}a_2+...+b_{n,n}a_n - c=b_{n,1}(a_1-c)+b_{n,2}(a_2-c)+...+b_{n,n}(a_n-c)$ hold? Also, for the first direction, why are you allowed to take $a_n$ to be $1$ for $n=j$ and $0$ for all other $n$, where $j$ is fixed?

Comment: Also, in the converse part, why does the sum go from $b_{n,1}(a_1-c)+b_{n,2}(a_2-c)+...+b_{n,n}(a_n-c)$ to $|b_{n,k}(a_{k}-c)+b_{n,k+1}(a_{k+1}-c)+...+b_{n,n}(a_n-c)|$ after you choose $k$?

Comment: @MilesDavis  Your fist query: $b_{n,1}c+b_{n,2}c+...+b_{n,n}c=c$. Second query: the hypothesis says 'for any convergent sequence $\{a_n\}$'. So we are free to choose  a particular convergent sequence. I have chosen one in which the terms become $0$ after some stage so that the sequence converges to $c=0$. Last query: I have split the sum from $1$ to $n$ into two parts: one from  $1$ to $k-1$ and another from $k$ to $n$.

Comment: Why does $b_{n,k+1} + b_{n,k+2} + \cdots b_{n,n} = 0$?

Comment: This is sum not $0$. It is $\leq 1$.